# different popup window styles for different tiered locations

Tags: carto, popup

New to cartodb, how can I have 1 map with multiple locations, and they can all have different amounts of popup data depending on the plan they purchased to get featured on our map?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to separate the data in layers in order to set up different infowindows for each of them.

We'd need more insights about the data you want to map, but if you have 4 different plans, you can split the dataset into 4 datasets, and then add all of them as layers. In each one of them you'll be able to style them in a different way directly from the CartoDB Editor.